# How do scientists focus high energy electromagnetic waves onto a target?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, experimental-physics

For visible light, we are able to use mirrors to focus on what we want.

However, gamma rays' wavelengths are too short and can't see solid objects.

So how do scientists focus high-energy electromagnetic waves onto a target and what would they use for such a process?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/physics-and-astronomy/gamma-ray-beams

Comment: https://www.llnl.gov/news/new-energy-record-set-multilayer-coated-mirrors

Comment: Gamma-ray images can be obtained using [Fresnel Zone Plate Coded Imagery](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/4665765), although the gamma rays are not focused.   FZPCI is a two-stop process somewhat like holography.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *grazing-angle reflection*, where the angle of incidence is very low, and build essentially a fresnel lens which will focus x-rays onto a detector array. This is the standard method for x-ray "optics" but I do not know if it has been used yet to focus gamma rays.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to aim a beam of gamma rays is collimation. You put your gamma source in a box with a hole in it, so that gamma rays only come out of the hole, and you point the hole at the object you want to irradiate.

It is also possible to create a strongly directional beam of high-energy photons by steering a beam of energetic charged particles, because an accelerated charge must radiate. This is the mechanism at Jefferson Lab's Free Electron Laser, where the electron beam "wiggles" so that the emitted light is coherent, and also at t HH e Advanced Light Source, where there is an experimental station at every corner of a not-quite-circular electron ring.